# Side-by-side (vertical) parallel translation of The Srimad-Bhagavatam and other works?

Tags: translation-request, sanskrit, translation

I'm seeking to learn Sanskrit in order to study a wider variety of Vedic literature that is not always translated into English or other languages. I would like to obtain all 30 volumes of the Srimad-Bhagavatam in Sanskrit + Transliterated Sanskrit + English.

I have seen such available works as [this hard copy](https://krishnastore.com/srimad-bhagavatam-set-original-first-edition-30-volume-h-krishna-502.html) ([PDF download](https://krishna.org/srimad-bhagavatam-original-edition-pdf-download/)), but I don't think I like the format of this and would like to find it in a vertical parallel format, more like what you might see from this example:
[image: parallel]

It would be nice to have a printed format, but an online source would be acceptable if no other option is available.

Comment: Vedabase has what you want, except the three are displayed horizontally. You have to click the text hyperlink to access it from the main translation page. https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/1/1/1/

Answer (score 2):

https://bhaktivedantavediclibrary.org/books/srimad-bhagavatam/

Hope this helps you. The books are translated by H.D.G A.C Bhaktivedanta Swami Srila Prabhupada, Founder-Acharya of the International Society for Krsna Consciousness. Hare Krishna!